# How to sort Array in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hello i have some simple code like this

```
  String[] myString1= {"Hidayat", "20"};
  outerArr.add(myString1);

  String[] myString2= {"Ryan", "10"};
  outerArr.add(myString2);

  String[] myString2= {"irwan", "5"};
  outerArr.add(myString2);
```

anyone know how to sort array outerArr with ascending by number?

Comment: What type of list you are using for outerArr?

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/java/how-sort-java-string-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface for custom sorting:

```
Collections.sort(outerArr, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2)
    {
        // for example you can compare integers
        return Integer.parseInt(o2[1]) - Integer.parseInt(o1[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: thx before, but how if an array is dynamic with loop

Comment: Your array changed at sorting time?

Comment: This is off topic on this post, but this will depends on your "dynamic array".

Answer (score 0):

For that case i prefer [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).The TreeMap class implements the Map interface by using a tree. A TreeMap provides an efficient means of storing key/value pairs in sorted order, and allows rapid retrieval.

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("20", "Hidayat");
map.put("10", "Ryan");
map.put("5", "irwan");
```

For retrieving the values

```
map.get("10"); // output = Ryan
```

Comment: You should add that this has some cost on each insertion, suppression of course so this depends on the usage. For a pretty static map, this is not a problem, for a list that will be update a lot but only need to be sorted (printed or used) once in a while, I would stay with a list

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this if you are using Java 8 is using Lambda, first create a class contain 2 member fields for the string and the number with getter for each member and then called this way :

```
outerArr.sort((Person o1, Person o2)->o1.getAge()-o2.getAge());
```

If you don't want to create a new class you can call :

```
outerArr.sort((String[] o1, String[] o2)->Integer.parseInt(o1[1])-Integer.parseInt(o2[1]));
```